# Getting error on "Blazor WASM hosted" Publish on IIS

Tags: iis, web-config, blazor

I have created sample Blazor WASM hosted application. (3.2 preview)
After building succesfully, without change any thing i directy published on iis

I am gettin this error ;
[image]

It seems like permision to reach web.config file,
I gived all permission to myuser,IUSR and IIS_USRS users,
I am still getting this error.

here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\BlazorApp7.Server.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 4fe4ba94-d473-4efb-91cd-82f2a0952c85-->
```

Answer (score 0):

When you host .net core web application in IIS, please ensure Asp.net core web hosting bundle has already been installed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Asp.net core web hosting bundle 3.1 is installed.

Comment: The error still looks like your asp.net core module not installed correctly.Could you find your AspNetCoreModule in IIS manager->site->modules?